# php mailer subject utf8

Tags: utf-8, phpmailer, subject

my mail form works very well. there is only problem in the subject line. If there is the letter "şğüöç" in the mail, the subject line is empty. It shows like this in MS Outlook program. =? Utf-8? Q ?? =

If there are no letters "şğüöç", the subject line is correct. I have read many articles. but i couldn't my head hurts, my brain burned.

```
 <?php

    require ("class.phpmailer.php");

        $gittiMesaji = " ";  

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $isimsoyisim            =$_POST['isimsoyisim'];
        $telefon                =$_POST['telefon'];
        $email                  =$_POST['email'];
        $dogumtarihi            =$_POST['dogumtarihi'];
        $tckimlik               =$_POST['tckimlik'];
        $yabanci                =$_POST['yabanci'];
        $dogumyeri              =$_POST['dogumyeri'];
        $askerlik               =$_POST['askerlik'];
        $ehliyet                =$_POST['ehliyet'];
        $medeni                 =$_POST['medeni'];
        $evlenmetarih           =$_POST['evlenmetarih'];
        $esbilgileri            =$_POST['esbilgileri'];
        $cocuk                  =$_POST['cocuk'];
        $ikamet                 =$_POST['ikamet'];
        $sabika                 =$_POST['sabika'];
        $temas                  =$_POST['temas'];
        $okul1                  =$_POST['okul1'];
        $okul1sehir1            =$_POST['okul1sehir1'];
        $okul1mezuniyettarih1   =$_POST['okul1mezuniyettarih1'];
        $okul2                  =$_POST['okul2'];
        $okul2sehir2            =$_POST['okul2sehir2'];
        $okul2mezuniyettarih2   =$_POST['okul2mezuniyettarih2'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.com';

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Username = 'no-reply@xxxxxxxxx.com';
        $mail->Password = '**********'; 
        $mail->CharSet  = 'utf-8';
        $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
        $mail->From = 'no-reply@xxxxxxxxx.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'Saffan Global';
        $mail->AddAddress ($email);
        $mail->AddCC ('webmaster@xxxxxxxxx.com');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = 'Basvuru - ' .$isimsoyisim;

        // HTML Message Starts here

        $mail->Body = "
        <html>
            <body>
                <table style='width:90%' align='center';>
                    <tbody>
```

Comment: Your first line: `require ("class.phpmailer.php");` tells me that you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: When I installed the new version, the white page came. no submissions. error.

Comment: Look at your web server’s error log, and read the PHPMailer docs.